# Zero Gate-Voltage Drain Current (IDss) vs Drain Source Voltage (Vds) relation for PMOS

Tags: mosfet, pmos, leakage-current, p-channel

The Drain to Source **leakage** current **Idss** at Zero Gate voltage (Vgs= 0) is normally 1uA(max).
However the relationship (or Graph) with Vds (Drain-source voltage) is not mentioned in Datasheet.

Que:

1. What is the relationship of **Idss** vs **Vds** when **Vgs = 0** for PMOS
   (P-channel MOSFET)? Linearly/Exponentially descreseing with Vds?
2. When Vgs=0 and Vds = 5, what will be Idss= ?
3. When Vgs=0 and Vds = 0, **Idss=0**?  (Where Vg !=0)
4. Will **Idss** decrease if **Vgs** is made **positive** e.g. +2V ?

I have attached Datasheet snippet of DMP2005UFG
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Good question; I mean it can't be 1 uA when VDS is zero volts so, how does it grow to become 1 uA as VDS rises above 0 volts. I have looked for this in the past and concluded that it has the same general shape as the characteristic when VGS is non zero. But that was based on intuitions rather than hard facts.

Comment: See chapter 14 of https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/user-manual/Nexperia_document_book_MOSFETGaNFETApplicationHandbook_2020.pdf Leakage of small-signal MOSFETs

Comment: Thank you @PeterSmith this App note provides insight into Leakage characteristics and answers many questions.

Comment: In summary: at Vgs=0, decreasing Vds will decrease Idss but marginally. In comparison Temperature has huge impact on Idss value. Lower the temperature lower the Idss.